# Функция при нажатии на option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте
Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на `option` появлялся дополнительный `div` под списком.

```
<select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
<div class="advance" style="display:none">Тут будут инпуты</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например, можно так (при смене варианта):

```js
jQuery("#sel").change(function(){
  jQuery(".advance").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="sel">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
<div class="advance" style="display:none">Тут будут инпуты</div>
```

Или так (при нажатии на любой вариант):

```js
jQuery("#sel").click(function(){
  jQuery(".advance").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="sel">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
<div class="advance" style="display:none">Тут будут инпуты</div>
```

Comment: При втором варианте div отображается уже при раскрытии - думаю, это не то, что нужно

Comment: @Cheg задача так сформулирована, что точно не ясно. _"Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на option"_. Первый вариант тогда не подходит потому что если выбирать ранее выбранный, то `div` не появляется, а во втором варианте появляется в любом случае.